# Transfom in vscode user snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code

My filename is `"TM_xxx_yyy.py"`, and suggested result is `"xxx.yyy"`.

I want it transferred by `"^TM_"` to `""` and `"_"` to `"."`. It seems I cannot transfer with two types of regex. How can I generate my snippets? Thanks!

My snippets so far is `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^TM_|_/./g}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/TM_([^_]+)_(.+)/$1.$2/}
```

Comment: Also, don't know if the filenames might be of any length, like `TM_xxx_yyy_zzz.py` etc. or `TM_xxx.py` but `"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/TM_([^_]+)|_([^_]+)/$1${2:+.}$2/g}"` will work for any length.

Comment: Very Nice!!! You solved the problem that has troubled me for a long time. Your second answer should be my solution. As a rookie of js, it's really hard for me to understand the tutorial. How can I inference the grammer like you?

Comment: Who were you directing the question to?  Me or rioV8?